# Css transition not working on mozilla

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, mozilla

I am building an transition with **:after** css and content in it using below code and Its working fine on chrome but not working on firefox 26.0. Why ?

Where i did wrong? I could not understand it ?
Help me out

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.teacherheading {
display: inline-block;
font-size:20px;
}

.teacherheading::after{content:'educational';

animation: 8s ease-out 2s pulsate;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-webkit-animation: 8s ease-out 2s pulsate;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 

-moz-animation: 8s ease-out 2s pulsate;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 

-o-animation: 8s ease-out 2s pulsate;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}


@-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {content:'educational';}
    25% {content:'testprep';}
    50% {content:'tutoring';}
    75% {content:'training';}
    100% {content:'educational';}
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {content:'educational';}
    25% {content:'testprep';}
    50% {content:'tutoring';}
    75% {content:'training';}
    100% {content:'educational';}
}

@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {content:'educational';}
    25% {content:'testprep';}
    50% {content:'tutoring';}
    75% {content:'training';}
    100% {content:'educational';}
}

@-o-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {content:'educational';}
    25% {content:'testprep';}
    50% {content:'tutoring';}
    75% {content:'training';}
    100% {content:'educational';}
}

</style>

<body>
<div style="font-size:20px">
Start your <div class="teacherheading"></div> institution
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create js fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The `content` property is not meant to be animatable.

Chrome seems to allow this (I do not know why) but Firefox is somewhat stricter.

Basically FF is following the intended behaviour, Chrome is not.

[**Content @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)

From Chris Coyier at [**CSS-Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/)

> In my own testing animating content has only worked in stable desktop Chrome (v46 at time of writing). No support anywhere else. No Safari on desktop or iOS. No Firefox. No IE. Each of these browsers will ignore the animation, showing only the original content in the pseudo element.
>
> It might be a handy trick in some distant future or it might never be supported by anything. Non-standard features are always at least at some risk of being deprecated, so this Chrome support may not last forever.
>
> If you need to change content in a cross-browser friendly way
>
> **Use JavaScript.**